# return a linked list of first n elements

Tags: java, linked-list, return

Ok guys I need to write a method; MyLinkedList getFirst(int n) – Returns a linked list of the first n elements. If the list is empty or n > size return null.

and I'm lost, I've done the mothods add, remove, add to middle, print a string of elements, and so on but this one has me stuck..

all I have so far is:

```
public MyLinkedList<E> getFirst(int n) {
    if(n > size ) {
        return null;
    }
    Node<E> current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i == n; i++) {
        current.next = new Node<E>(e);
    }
}
```

I know this code is pretty wrong but its all I can think of been working on this assignment for a while and I'm just running out of steam I guess lol

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: homework? this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: homework is fine if someone has genuinely tried to solve the problem by himself/herself before asking.

Comment: Frankly, it does not look like, that you have worked on this for "a while".

Comment: "a while" didn't mean this one problem in particular, this is my first time using linked list and I had many other methods to write, this is just one I'm stuck on, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an empty list
2. Add the head to the list
3. Continuing adding the next node to the list until you have the first n nodes.

Comment: thanks, I updated my code a bit, is this heading in the right direction?

Comment: Your loop doesn't look right. At some point you need to return a `MyLinkedList<E>` object, which I assume is something you have written yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public MyLinkedList getFirstN(int n) {
    MyLinkedList firstNList=new MyLinkedList();//create an empty list
    if(n>size)
        firstNList= null;
    else {
        Node tmp=head; //initialise tmp Node to the head(beginning) of list
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            firstNList.add(tmp);//add current node to the end of list
            tmp=tmp.getNext();
        }
    }
    return firstNList;
}
```

Implement the `add(Node node)` method to append a `Node` to the end of list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as prototype and proceed with any operation

```
public class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node(int data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

}


public class LinkedList {
    private Node start;

    public LinkedList() {
        start = null;
    }

    public void insert(int x) {
        if(start == null) {
            start = new Node(x, start);
        } else {  
            Node temp = start;

            while(temp.getNext() != null) {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            Node newNode = new Node(x,null);
            temp.setNext(newNode);
        }
    }

    public void getFirst() {
        if(start == null) {
            System.out.println("\n List is empty !!");
        }
        else  {
            Node temp = start;
            System.out.println("\n First Element is --->" + temp.getData());
        }
    }

}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

        System.out.println("\n--- Inserting 100 ---\n");
        ll.insert(100);

        ll.insert(101);
        ll.insert(102);
        ll.insert(103);

        System.out.println("\n--- First Element ---\n");
        ll.getFirst();

    } 

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the OP can't use Java implementation of LinkedList as this is an exercise on Data Structures.. :D

Comment: OP in the sense, you mean operation

Comment: OP = original poster :D http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean